# How to convert object of a class into string and run insert query

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to store session data into another table. so that's why i am fetching session data into one variable and trying to insert it. when i am printing this data it will not give any problem. help me in this.it gives error

**error:**

> Severity: 4096 Message: Object of class stdClass could not be
>   converted to string

**temp_model.php**// this is my model file

```
<?php

class Temp_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function add_admin_id()
    {
        echo "welcome to temp_model";
        $s = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
        /*echo"<pre>";
        print_r($s);
        exit; */

        $query = $this->db->insert('super_admin',$s);

        if($query==run) {
            echo "new data inserted successfully";
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "failed to insert new data";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont think `var_dump($query) = $this->db->insert('super_admin',$s);` is valid syntax

Comment: What is `run` in this statement `if($query==run)` Its not a variable and its not a string literal. **Have you looked at the error log**??

Comment: That error message normally comes with a line number!! Look at that line number and you should see the error, if not then tell us which line is generating the error

Comment: RiggsFolly : Sorry for var_dump() fun i am just trying to see what happened when use this..

Comment: have you any idea that how to store $S variable values in database?

Comment: Your Insert query is wrong.Learn [How to write Insert query](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) `$s` Should be an array or object not string. And Include full error message.Seems the  error message you mentioned  is coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you can do another thing to store hole date to filed while you don`t exactly know 
what key word the session array may contains . or want to store theme in an single filed .

like follow

```
$this->db->insert('super_admin',array('column_name'=>json_encode($s)));
```

or if the table is having the fields then just convert the object to array use should be like this

```
  $this->db->insert('super_admin',(array) $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this codeIgniter documentation about SESSION http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html. Behind the scene it is using normal PHP session so there is no possibility of changing value type. It will store value as you insert into it. So it would be better to check your code & its value type by using var_dump() function instead of print_r() function.